# How can I create a GUI in Java using only code and not the graphical drag and drop? [uber-newbie]

Tags: java

I've been told that creating GUI's using drag and drop generates unnecesary code and is frowned upon by most Java developers.

I'm used to dragging and dropping things using Windows Forms **but ** I'm also very comfortable creating things using XAML for WPF applications.

I'm a bit lost however on how to create a basic GUI in Java using only code.

> **What I'm using:** Netbeans 6.8
>
> **What I want to do:** Create a simple Window that will act as the main one
>   that opens up when the application
>   launches.

How can I create a simple Window with the standard window buttons (close, minimize, maximize) and have a little button on the middle of it. Using only code.

Also, what type of project do I create using NetBeans?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard that one before. I don't know what is with java developers and always insisting that you have to write the gui by code and can't use drag and drop tools. For me I don't care if it generates unnecessary code. I personally don't think it will make that much of a difference.

The only thing I would never recommend is using a designer for websites since they usually never look the way you designed it when you actually test it on a browser but for windows GUI just use a designer.

I look at it this way. There might be a bit more of unnecessary code but your bosses won't care about that. They will be more concerned why your taking so much longer on something and costing the company so much more money on little to no effect to the final product.

To answer your question you probably can pick up any book from java and they will have tutorials on how to make GUI's by code.

Comment: Is that true? Does generating GUI by drag and drop really not impact performance is a noticible manner? If the effect really is insignificant, I guess I'll just disregard the commons about doing things visually.

Comment: Your time as a programmer is far more valuable than any extra clock cycles spent in the generated code.

Comment: Well Papuccion1, I never tested it and I do more C# programming then java programming so I always just use the gui builder. But I can't immagine that it will make so much of a difference and when a company is paying you like $25+/hour they rather take a very little bit of a hit in performance then pay 100's more to get those couple clock cycles.

Comment: I guess you're right. I'm still interested in a knowledgable technical answer though. Does it really impact the application?

Comment: Ya I am interested it in too. I always like to know how much impact something has. So if anyone has speed tests on this I would love to see them too. However I would not get wrapped up on these small little issues try to learn big issues that will really effect the speed of an application then these little nit picky things.

Comment: It's not an execution speed issue - it's a software development time issue.  You might save some time doing the initial GUI work slapping some components on a form - the real loss comes later, when you need to refactor or maintain the app. Or you update or change your IDE and it doesn't understand the old GUI builder's special format.  Or you unknowingly have a runtime dependency on some library provided by the GUI builder... etc. etc.

Comment: I've done a lot of GUIs, both by D&D and by hand. D&D code is a little more verbose (up to 2-3x) than hand coded, but the performance hit is not really noticeable. Remember, a GUI is intended to interact with humans, who are comically slow. The bigger disadvantage of "assisted coding" is that the produced code is often difficult to maintain/extend. Another problem I've encountered is that the GUI builder suddenly chokes in mid-work because you've blown its little mind. Sometimes no choice but to proceed by hand. I'm good with layouts, so now I prefer hand code.

Answer (score 6):

I feel like this kind of question is best answered with a link to a tutorial, so here you go:

From java.sun.com, [Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Thank you for that link, I'll most definitely read it. However right now I'm just looking for this particular issue so I can understand how it works. I can tinker around with different things from there.

Comment: In that case, post the code that you have and the reason it isn't working as you'd like, and someone will surely help.

Comment: I don't have any code otherwise this question would be much much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The link provided by **danben** is really helpful. If you really want to lay out everything from scratch, then you have to be able to answer such questions as

- What is container? Which components are containers?
- How components are positisioned within a container (layout manager)?

The link provided will give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do it programatically, you have to be able to understand code in general. As far as I know Java does not have a simple XML based layout language for GUI-s. So first you have to learn how to program. (But you can try JavaFX's script language, might be easier to master first.) You can easily learn your way in the simple cases from the generated code, then continue using swing javadoc and google.

GUI builders are handful, nevertheless. It is a plausible that once you are required to mock up a GUI layout as a prototype, tracer bullet, presentation material etc. Generated code might be even completely irrelevant.